# The letters of the word REGAIN when arranged as per dictianory, find the 32nd word.

Tags: permutations

> The letters of the word REGAIN when arranged as per dictianory, find the 32nd word.

a)AEGIRN

b)AEGRIN

c)AEIGRN

d)none of these

**MyApproach**

As per dictionary order,  alphabets will  follow the order AEGINR.

Now,Starting with A,other letters will have 5! ways to form i.e $120$.Hence 32 word will not be there.

Starting with AE letters will have $24$ letters....1

Staring with AGE letters will have $6$ letters.....2

> But I am confused how to follow the Ans from here.
>   Can anyone guide me  how to follow this approach?

Comment: So from what you have written ..you are saying that number of words starting with $AE$ will be equal to $24 (4×3×2×1)$  and we are required to find 32nd word ..so as all the words given in option start with $AE$ and as $24<32$ so whatever the 32nd word will be it will surely not start with $AE$ but all the options given here start with $AE$ ....so naturally one answer is left!!...you can Also specifically calculate 32nd word...but since it was a multiple choice question...so i don't think there is a problem with this...

Comment: I think you were close to a correct analysis. The first $4!=24$ words begin with AE. So the $32$-nd word cannot begin with AE.

Comment: @AndréNicolas AGE will have letters till 30 Its 30 letter will be AGERNI Am i right?. 31 and 32  will be  AGIENR.32 word will be AGIERN

Comment: Yes, the next $3!$ after the words that begin with AE start with AGE. And then you got the next two right, so you correctly found word $32$. But this was not necessary to answer the multiple choice question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it's AGIERN so the correct answer is "none of these".

AEGxxx -> 6

AEIxxx -> 6

AENxxx -> 6

AERxxx -> 6

AGExxx -> 6

and then the next two are:

AGIENR
AGIERN

So the answer is AGIERN.